# How to manually create empty MongoDB index on a new field?

Tags: mongodb

I have a huge collection, more than 2TiB of data. During release of a new feature I add an index of new field, that 100% sure doesn't exist in any document, MongoDB will still perfom a full scan for this field, which may process for a long time.

Is there any hack to just manually create an empty index file with valid structure and notify MongoDB node about it, so it will load index into memory and everything else MongoDB is doing when index is crerated?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in relational RDBMS, MongoDB creates indexes also on non-existing fields, i.e. it scans the entire collection.

Index creation runs in background, so it should not harm so much.

See [createIndexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/command/createIndexes/)

> Changed in version 4.2.
>
> For feature compatibility version (fcv) "4.2", all index builds use an optimized build process that holds the exclusive lock only at the beginning and end of the build process. The rest of the build process yields to interleaving read and write operations. MongoDB ignores the background option if specified.

If you run MongoDB version 4.2 or earlier, then you may specify option `{ background: true }`

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that actual creation of an "not yet created field" index could last several hours and result will be an empty structure. I'm wondering how can I overcome this process and just manually set-up all structures.

Comment: Maybe use `{sparse: true}`, see [Sparse Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/index-sparse/)